# How to merge three dataframes into one and drop the duplicates also?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to merge three dataframes into one and after that I am trying to drop duplicates also but not getting the result. Can you please help me how to do this?

I am giving you the total number of records in df1, df2, and df3 have.

Example:

```
df1 -- 18151
df2 -- 184
df3 -- 77425392
```

All the dataframe are having the same header also.

Expected Output:

```
df_final = pd.concat([df3, df2, df1], axis=1, ignore_index=True)

df_final -- 77443727
```

I am trying to drop duplicates also using this code but not working.

```
df_final = df_final[['SOURCE_ID', 'SOURCE_COLUMN_VALUE']].drop_duplicates()
```

Comment: Can you include a sample of your dataframe and also the expected output ?

Comment: What is the output you see? "not working" is rather general.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have used the wrong syntax for `drop_duplicates()` :

```py
df_final.drop_duplicates(subset=['SOURCE_ID', 'SOURCE_COLUMN_VALUE'], keep=False, inplace=True)
```

Try this !

Comment: but first challenge is merging 3 dataframe into one.. So how to do this?

Comment: Please include the dataframe structures bro, it's hard to try out.